# STM32F429 I2C problem

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

is it possible to connect two I2C busses on one board, one at master mode and the other in slave. I am just trying to learn some I2C stuff, but I have only one board.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The ST Micro [STM32F429 datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00071990.pdf) says it has three I2C peripherals, so as long as the pins are available, you can connect them together, and use one as a master and the other as a slave.

If the pins of all three I2C peripherals are available, you could connect all three, and do a bunch of experiments to learn how to use I2C in multi-slave and multi-master configurations.

You should be quite careful about how interrupts are used. However, you can probably ignore using more than one interrupt, and still learn a lot.

There is an [STM32F429-Discovery](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/CL1620/SC959/SS1532/LN1848/PF259090) development board. If you are using that there are libraries to drive the peripherals. One is the older CMSIS-based [STM32F429-Discovery Firmware](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259429), another is [STM32CubeF4](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259243).

There are a bunch of low cost I2C slave devices. As suggested in the comments, there are I2C EEPROM chips, and I've used low-cost I2C temperature sensors (under one GCP), to test software.

Comment: As above, yes.  However, I2C EEPROMs are pretty cheap and they are a known-working device so when you're debugging and it doesn't work, you know who to blame ;)  I would not like to start from scratch implementing both endpoints, though you can certainly work towards that point with all three I2C peripherals connected together.